# What is the purpose of hyphenated attribute naming and how it works?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, data-binding, hyphenation

I am creating a component (vue 2.6) and just realised that if the attribute `class` is not hyphenated actually doesn't deliver the string to the component. And other attributes with no hyphenated names do deliver their values. This is how my code looks like:

Component:

```
<template>
  <video
    controls
    :class="cssClass"
  >
    <source :src="videoSource" type="video/mp4"/>
  </video>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'VideoComponent',
  props: {
    videoSource: { type: String, default: '' },
    cssClass: { type: String, default: '' },
  },
};
</script>
```

How I am using it:

```
<VideoComponent
  v-if="selectedAsset.type == 'video'"
  css-class="cssClassName"
  :videoSource="selectedAsset.videoSource"
/>
```

So if I name the attribute `cssClass` and not `css-class` when I am using it in the father component, `VideoComponent` does not receive it and is empty BUT `videoSource` works fine...
Why it works with some attributes and the others not?

To use same naming for attributes and properties when I use a component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VideoSource` is an object, so it will be passed as an object directly to your `src` prop.

As for the props, there is a convention: https://vuejs.org/style-guide/rules-strongly-recommended.html#prop-name-casing

Follow it: `css-class` (kebab-case) for the prop when passing it to a component, and `cssClass` (camelCase) when receiving it in the child component.

EDIT: it should of course be `:css-class` aka `v-bind:class-css` otherwise it is not passed as a reactive object but as a regular string.

Vue devtools can help you here.